# Open a new window in javascript/Jquery Spring MVC project

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function opendocument()
{
 window.open("www.google.com");         
}
```

I am working on Spring MVC project.It is opening like http://localhost:8080/Sample/www.google.com.  How to open only www.google.com?.

Comment: What is `Sample`? Do you mean `window.open("https://www.google.com");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the HTTP (or HTTPS if you wish) protocol:

```
function opendocument()
{
     window.open("http://www.google.com");         
}
```